# Tools to mock network requests

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, subdomain, port

I hosted my Angular 6 and Laravel application on an AWS EC2 Instance, the angular container is running on(or mapped to) port 80 and 443 served by Nginx while the Laravel application is running on another container running on (or mapped to) port 8000 also served by Nginx.

I configured the angular app to be running at https://example.com and the Laravel app on https://api.example.com.

To be clear, the containers are task on separate services in the same EC2 Cluster on a cloud formation and there is no load-balancer.

The set up works perfectly for like 97% of customers but the remaining customers cannot get content on the site. I worked with one of the customers and realized that the Angular app(at https://example.com) loaded successfully but https://api.example.com:8000 cannot be reached.

What on earth can cause this?

Is there a way (may be tool) I can use to simulate different kinds of network request so that I can simulate the problematic network of the customers that cannot assess the site, for me to be able to trace and debug, because right now I am not having issue, making the problem very dicey for me to solve.